# PHP variable variables in {} symbols

Tags: php

I get the basics of variable variables, but I saw a syntax just know, which bogles my mind a bit.

```
$this->{$toShow}();
```

I don't really see what those {} symbols are doing there. Do they have any special meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP's variable parser isn't greedy. The {} are used to indicate what should be considered part of a variable reference and what isn't. Consider this:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[3] = array();
$arr[3][4] = 'Hi there';

echo "$arr[3][4]";
```

Notice the double quotes. You'd expect this to output `Hi there`, but you actually end up seeing `Array[4]`. This is due to the non-greediness of the parser. It will check for only ONE level of array indexing while interpolating variables into the string, so what it really saw was this:

```
echo $arr[3], "[4]";
```

But, doing

```
echo "{$arr[3][4]}";
```

forces PHP to treat everything inside the braces as a variable reference, and you end up with the expected `Hi there`.

Answer (score 4):

They tell the parser, where a variable name starts and ends. In this particular case it might not be needed, but consider this example:

```
$this->$toShow[0]
```

What should the parser do? Is `$toShow` an array or `$this->$toShow` ? In this case, the variable is resolved first and the array index is applied to the resulting property.

So if you actually want to access `$toShow[0]`, you have to write:

```
$this->{$toShow[0]}
```

Answer (score 3):

These curly braces can be used to use expressions to specify the variable identifier instead of just a variable’s value:

```
$var = 'foo';
echo ${$var.'bar'};  // echoes the value of $foobar
echo $$var.'bar';    // echoes the value of $foo concatenated with "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->{$toShow}();
```

Break it down as below:

First this is a object oriented programming style as you got to see `$this and ->`. Second, `{$toShow}()` is a method(function) as you can see the () brackets.

So now `{$toShow}()` should somehow be parsed to a name like '`compute()`'. And, $toShow is just a variable which might hold a possible function name. But the question remains, why is {} used around.

The reason is {} brackets substitues the value in the place. To clarify,

```
$toShow="compute";
```

so,

```
{$toShow}(); //is equivalent to compute();
```

but this is not true:

```
$toShow();     //this is wrong as a variablename is not a legal function name
```